# produce images with shapefiles and OpenStreetMap

Tags: python, openstreetmap, mapnik

I have a python file http://pastebin.com/jzwE6c6P which iterates over the features of a shapefile and renders a simple image by zooming to the bounding box of each feature. What I need is OpenstreetMap as a basemap. I have OpenStreetMap successfully loaded in a postis database. I can produce an OpenStreetMap with the mapnik example generate_image.py, but I have no idea how to call the osm file.

http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik/generate_image.py

Any help would be greatly appreciated